# Como "empacotar" funções do python de uma classe que será utilizada em outra classe?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, self

Apesar de ser leigo em POO, estou tentando criar uma classe que contem diversas funções que são de uso em comum para outras classes. No caso, eu gostaria de empacotar essas funções em "sub-blocos" para organizar melhor o código, e chamar essas funções através de "sub-objetos" ou algo do tipo. Abaixo segue um código com exemplo do que tenho em mente.

```
class obj_pri:
        
    class pacote_func1:        
        def funcao1(self):
           self.atrib = 5
            
class obj_sec(obj_pri):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.atrib = 2

teste = obj_sec()
teste.pacote_func1.funcao1()
```

No exemplo a cima eu esperava que o atributo self.atrib atualizasse seu valor de 2 para 5. Porem, ocorre um erro do tipo "funcao1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". Alguem teria uma sugestão de como resolver esse problema do não reconhecimento do self ou como "empacotar funções que deverão ser utilizadas em outro objeto" de uma maneira funcional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens que usar parênteses na classe interna para a instanciar e tens que definir a classe pai para poderes aceder aos atributos da classe pai.

```
class obj_pri:
    class pacote_func1:
        def __init__(self, obj_pri):
            self.obj_pri = obj_pri

        def funcao1(self):
            self.obj_pri.atrib = 5
            
class obj_sec(obj_pri):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.atrib = 2

teste = obj_sec()
print(teste.atrib)
teste.pacote_func1(teste).funcao1()
print(teste.atrib)
```